# Displaying ajax requested JSON objects into HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, highcharts

Basically, I'm wanting to display the current temp of a city in highcharts, alongside the comparison of the expected minimum and maximum temperatures.

Currently this is my ajax request on the data, the data is then stored in a variable 'owDataJSON' which I manipulate.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "jsonp",
type:'GET',
url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/......",
data: Object,
success: function(owData){

owDataJSON = owData;
max = owDataJSON.main.temp_max;
temp = owDataJSON.main;
min = owDataJSON.main.temp_min;

 console.log(owData)


     }
  });
```

I then draw the chart using -

```
$(function () {


    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series:  [{

            data: //what goes here?

        }]
     });
    });
```

I'm wanting to know how to draw the chart? I've tried to iterate through an array but that doesn't appear to be working, the JSON data called from the URL is constantly changing so it's dynamic. I've also tried to pass 'owData' into the highcharts function and call it in the data property of series, still can't seem to get it going.

Basically when I output the data I want, I'm given a JSON object like such -

```
{temp: 301.15, pressure: 1007, humidity: 74, temp_min: 301.15, temp_max: 301.15}
```

Which is in correct highcharts format (I think), I want to print onto highcharts -  the current temp, the min temp and the max temp. Any help would be greatly appreciate as I'm stuck on what to do next.

Thank you

Comment: Show us `owData` - how respond look like?

Comment: The respond looks like   

    {temp: 301.15, pressure: 1007, humidity: 74, temp_min: 301.15,       temp_max: 301.15}

Comment: 1) Create chart inside `success` callback. 2) Convert data to Highcharts format (simple for() loop with pushing to the new array). 3) Every time when user refreshes your page, you will load most recent data, but don't forget to set `cache` property to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass data to `series` as array of objects, so for example if you want to write chart with average temperatures per month in London you need to pass:

```
series: [{
  name: 'London',
  data: [10, 12, 16, 17, 16, 18, 22, 18, 15, 3, 4, 5]
}]
```

Next city will be next object in `series` array.

Here is full working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/o9ezjsuo/), and modified with dynamic data [example2](https://jsfiddle.net/o9ezjsuo/2/)

Comment: What if the data is dynamic? The data changes everyday? :/

Comment: @BravoWhiskey i add dynamic data in second example, but connot understound what is the point, of your question.

Comment: Thats just local data within an array. The data im using is coming from an API. I'm basically trying to put that API data into highcharts - and this is the JSON object = {temp: 301.15, pressure: 1007, humidity: 74, temp_min: 301.15, temp_max: 301.15}

Comment: @BravoWhiskey but your chart is design for only average temperature, so you want get average and parse this data for `HighCharts` standart which look like this in my answer, next execute `.highcharts()` again, like i doing in interval. Interval from my example is simulating your ajax `success` callback

Comment: Ok, I seem to be heading in the wrong direction, I've spoken with a mate who's given me some insight on the issue and I'm heading in the right direction now, thanks so much for your help dude - sorry for confusing you lol